# Как определить настройку скроллинга natural (Mac) vs. reverse (Win)?

Tags: прокрутка, ux, javascript, браузер

Делаю свой горизонтальный скроллинг. Понял, что привычки пользователей разных платформ противоположны: в Windows двигают «окно», через которое смотрят на контент, а в Mac OS X двигают контент относительно этого «окна». Впрочем, в Mac OS X это поведение настраивается — некоторые оставили у себя «обратный» — как в Windows — скроллинг.

Сделал [макет проблемы](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/0zzfajyp/embedded/result/).

---

*Upd.* Новая формулировка вопроса:

**– Как определить, в какую сторону у посетителя работает скроллинг, не заставляя его делать дополнительных действий?**

В частном случае – Safari, покрутили колёсиком – можно узнать настройки ([отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23668035/556876)):

```
function myWheelEventHandler(event) {
  var deltaY = -event.wheelDeltaY;
  if (event.webkitDirectionInvertedFromDevice) deltaY = -deltaY;
  // use value for something
}
```

Хочется найти способ и для других браузеров — FF, Chrome.

Comment: @Sergiks, вначале немного не так понял суть вопроса, теперь разобравшись думаю, что если у вас будет, к примеру, сайт с горизонтальным параллаксом, то на самом деле нужно делать разные варианты для Windows и Mac по тачпаду на ноутбуке, но при этом для планшетов-телефонов вариант всегда один - тащится контент слева направо.

Comment: @Sergiks: А разве user agent (то есть, браузер) не делает это за вас в соответствии с пользовательскими настройками?

Comment: @VladD браузер делает для колеса прокрутки и стандартных скролбаров. А у меня кастом кнопки.

Comment: @Sergiks: Хм. А нельзя ли просто застилизовать стандартные каким-то образом, чтобы они выглядели как кастомные? Это бы решило проблему на корню. (Наверное.)

Comment: @VladD застилизовать [не выйдет в FF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox/6165489#6165489). Поэтому решение может быть костыльным: рисовать прозрачный div нужного размера поверх, скроллить его нативными барами, и транслировать его положение через JS в мой контент. Ад?

Comment: @Sergiks: С одной стороны — ну да, ад. С другой стороны — если этот грязный код документирован и не заставляет окружающий код быть грязным (то есть, хак скрыт внутри и не виден снаружи), то это меньшее из зол.